Gitlab variable as component input
With gitlab ci, is there a way to give a variable to a component input?
Something like this:
include:
  - component: path/to/component@main
    inputs:
      var: ${VARIABLE}

where $VARIABLE value is dynamically defined in a previous job?
What would be an alternative?
How the component and the pipeline could be modified to support this use case?
Thanks

A job runs as part of a pipeline and, as such, components have already been resolved.
You could get around this by triggering a secondary pipeline and passing variables to it that would then be used.
trigger job:
  stage: deploy
  trigger:
    include: child.gitlab-ci.yaml
  variables:
    VARIABLE: bar # child pipeline will use this as a parameter to the component.


Unfortunately it does not work. the child pipeline will look like the initial example and the gitlab ci will raise an error related to the fact that a variable is provided as input instead of a string (for example).
